# Difficulties in converting RGBA to float and back

Tags: hlsl

I can't get my colors back.

What I'm using to encode/decode:

```
static const float Scale = 255.0f;//or 256 not working either
static const float Scale2 = Scale*Scale;
static const float Scale3 = Scale2*Scale;
static const float Scale4 = Scale3*Scale;
static const float4 bitSh = float4( 1.0f, Scale, Scale2, Scale3);
static const float4 bitMsk = float4(1.0f/Scale, 1.0f/Scale, 1.0f/Scale, 0);
static const float4 bitShifts = float4(1.0, 1.0/Scale, 1.0/Scale2, 1.0/Scale3);
```

RGBA to Float to be stored as R16_FLOAT or UNORM (I've tried both none works fine)

```
float C16 = dot(Color, bitShifts);
Output.Color = C16;
```

float to RGBA

```
float4 C16 = txDiffuse.Load(int3(960*Input.Tex.x, 540*Input.Tex.y, 0)).r*bitSh;
float4 rgba = frac(C16);
rgba -=rgba.yzww*bitMsk;
float4 Color = rgba;
```

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453302/how-do-you-pack-one-32bit-int-into-4-8bit-ints-in-glsl-webgl) some additional modifications can be used to take care about preсision. What I have when manipulating the rgb is either a full red or full blue scene. There is also a problem with the frac result that gives flickering random colors.

The bitXXX data can be reversed (e.g. xyzw values are in wzyx order) but the results are the same.

Comment: Do you understand what the code you wrote does?

Comment: What I understand is that you take the color component [0..1], multiplied each by an inversed increasing power of 256 ti match what we did on cpu with bitshift to pack 4 8bit in a dword.

Comment: I don't know HLSL but in GLSL you don't have to pack and unpack colour values. You can write RGBA unsigned bytes to the texture and read it as floats and it's converted automatically. I don't really understand what you're doing here.

Comment: for some reasons I want to transform R8G8B8A8 to fit in a R16 format. This was regularly made to convert Depth [0..1] in 3 or 4  8bits textures. I've done this in a previous post (D24 to 2 A8) with success to store depth in 2 unused alpha chanels to save resources  (https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/201151/24bit-float-to-rgb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it working as follow:

First solution

Using a rendertarget/shaderresource R16_UINT, with the restriction of using texture.Load when used as SRV.

take benefit of bitshifting in SM5. Can be replace by appropriate multiplication/division with power of 2 as shown in the second solution

```
 Encode RGB to R16, 
 uint3 C16 = uint3(min(Color.rgb*255.0,float3(255.0,255.0,255.0)));
 //using min to ensure the color is in the range 0..255 otherwise if value > 255 black color can be obtained
 uint OutColor  = (C16.r & 0xf8)>>3 | (C16.g & 0xfc)<<3 |(C16.b & 0xf8)<<8;

 Decode R16 to R5G6B5
 uint C16 = txDiffuse.Load(int3(Input.Tex.xy*float2(myresolutionXY),0)).r;
 uint3 i3C16 = uint3(C16 & 0x001F, (C16 & 0x07E0)>>5,(C16 & 0xF800)>>11);
 float4 Color = float4(float3(1.0/31.0,1.0/63.0,1.0/31.0)*i3C16,1);
```

Second solution

the f_f4 and f4_f functions are inspired from [there](https://community.monogame.net/t/deferred-physically-based-rendering-storing-four-8-bit-values-in-one-32-bit-value-using-hlsl/13472)

Using a rendertarget/shaderresource R16_UNORM

Encode RGB to R16_UNORM

```
Output.Color0  = f4_f(min(float4(Color,Flag & dwReflexPlane), float4(1,1,1,1)));
//using min to ensure the color is in the range 0..1 otherwise if value > 1 black color can be obtained
```

With

```
float f4_f(float4 f4Value)
{
    uint r, g, b, a;
    r = uint(f4Value.r * 31.0f);
    g = uint(f4Value.g * 63.0f)*32;//bitshit version uint(f4Value.g * 63.0f)<<5;
    b = uint(f4Value.b * 31.0f)*2048;//bitshit version uint(f4Value.b * 31.0f)<<11;
    a = 0;//;
    return = float((r | g | b | a)/65535.0);
```

}

Decode R16_UNORM to R5G6B5

```
 float4 ColorTx = f_f4(txDiffuse.SampleLevel(samPoint, Input.Tex, 0));
```

with f_f4

```
 float4 f_f4(float fValue)
 {
     uint uiValue = uint(fValue*65535);
     float4 f4Value;
     f4Value.r = (uiValue & 0x001F) / 31.0f;
     f4Value.g = ((uiValue & 0x07E0) /32) / 63.0f;//bitshift version ((uiValue & 0x07E0) >> 5) / 63.0f;
     f4Value.b = ((uiValue & 0xF800) /2048) / 31.0f;//bitshift version ((uiValue & 0xF800) >> 11) / 31.0f;
     f4Value.a = 1;

     return f4Value;

 }
```

Should be adapted to R5G5B5A1 if 1bit alpha is need

Finally these previous packing solutions were not totally satisfactory for my needs.

My multitarget deferred pipeline requires an alpha channel for blending with at least 1 bit to work properly, not possible with these previous solutions. Also UINT did not accept blending.

The other problem to solve was the maximum of 8 simultaneous render target in my card. The problem here was that my current screen space reflection was using 3 layers to show occluded parts using the 8 RTVs, all rendered in one pass. It appears that a 4th layer may be needed in some cases. Each layer requires 3 information’s : color, normal depth. So at least 12 render targets.

The only way to solve this is to pack the color and its normal in one render target and accept some loss of quality.
In addition my card is sensitive to bandwith pressure and using format like R16G16B16A16 is more demanding and the highest RTV format available is R32G32.
So I selected R10B10G10A2 as the most convenient format for me and find how to pack color and normal in R10G10B10

Packing Color.rgb as R55G5 and Normal.xyz as G5B55 with 2 bits Alpha

```
 float4 f331_R10G10B10A2(float3 Color, float3 Normal, float Alpha)
 {
     float4 Out;
     //min ensures that the value is in the range [0..31] otherwise incorrect colors will be obtained when unpaking
     uint3 uColor = uint3(min(Color*31.0,   float3(31, 31, 31)));
     uint3 uNormal = uint3(min(Normal*31.0,   float3(31, 31, 31)));
    Out = float4((uColor.r | (uColor.g<<5)), 
                (uColor.b | (uNormal.r<<5)), 
                (uNormal.g | (uNormal.b<<5)), Alpha*1023.0);    
     return Out/1023.0;
 }
```

Unpack R10B10G10A2 to Color, Normal and Alpha

```
 void R10G10B10A2_f331(float4 Pack, inout float3 Color, inout float3 Normal, inout float Alpha)
 {
     uint4 iPack = uint4(Pack*1023.0);
     Color = float3( iPack.r&0x1F, (iPack.r>>5)&0x1F,iPack.g&0x1F)/31.0f;
     Normal = float3((iPack.g>>5)&0x1F, iPack.b&0x1F, (iPack.b>>5)&0x1F)/31.0f;
     Alpha = Pack.a!=0;//in my app alpha is used only as 0/1 value
 }
```

Now my pipeline as 4 RTVs for the 4 layers and 1 RTV to store the corresponding depths in R16B16G16A16.
Next step : produce a texture for bumpiness (SSR works very slow with bump) and maybe pack normal as 2 8 bits for better quality. Various methods are explained [here](https://aras-p.info/texts/CompactNormalStorage.html) . 555 normals format is not precise enough for screen space reflection.

Comment: Be sure to mark this answer as Accepted by clicking the checkmark in the top-left corner, if this solves your problem.

Comment: says can do it tomorrow